# TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Amigos tengo un código de un botón flotante de manera que al bajar en la pagina el botón se muestre de forma automática y se oculte cuando esta arriba en la pagina, el codigo me funciona perfecto usando html css y javascript.... pero ahora que ando en el mundo de react js quiero darle uso a ese codigo, este es el codigo del boton flotante en javascript puro:

```
css
.cmn-divfloat {
    position: fixed !important;
    bottom: 45px;
    right: 15px;
    display: none;
}
.cmn-btncircle {
    width: 40px !important;
    height: 40px !important;
    padding: 6px 0px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}

html
<div id="div-totop" class="cmn-divfloat">
    <a href="#span-top" class="btn btn-primary cmn-btncircle">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
    </a>
</div>

javascript
(function() {
    //a partir de que punto del scroll vertical de la ventana mostrará el botón
    const ishow = 115
    const $divtop = document.getElementById("div-totop")
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
        if(document.documentElement.scrollTop > ishow){
            $divtop.style.display = "inherit"
        }
        else {
            $divtop.style.display = "none"
        }
    })
})()
```

Trate de transportarlo a react pero me aaroja error en esta linea:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    (anonymous function)
    C:/Users/cli/Documents/React/news/src/Component/Nav/Nav.js:38
      35 |             $divtop.style.display = "inherit"
      36 |         }
      37 |         else {
    > 38 |             $divtop.style.display = "none"
      39 |         }
      40 |     })
      41 | })()
    View compiled
```

componente en react JS

```
export default class Nav extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="navbar-fixed-left">
                <ul>
              
                </ul>
                <div id="div-totop" class="cmn-divfloat">
                <a href="#span-top" class="btn btn-primary cmn-btncircle">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}

function = () => {
   
    const ishow = 115
    const $divtop = document.getElementById("div-totop")
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
        if(document.documentElement.scrollTop > ishow){
            $divtop.style.display = "inherit"
        }
        else {
            $divtop.style.display = "none"
        }
    })
}
```

¿Para el caso de react js que debo cambiarle?

Hay algo que no entiendo, que es que uno declaraba la funcion y desde javascript se manejaba, ahora desde react no entiendo muy bien como se deberia llamar esa función,

gracias de antemano

Comment: puedes poner el código del componente de react, como lo estás intentando?

Comment: Concuerdo con @Tasio, sin tu código no se te puede ayudar. También te recomiendo cambiar el estilo de tus componentes de react de acuerdo a lo que dice [la documentación](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html) y no hacerlo como si fuese JS simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con ReactJS es posible devolver (render) el mismo árbol de elementos vDOM en repetidas ocasiones (re-render) modificando los valores (el estado) de sus propiedades; esto permite **repensar la forma de diseñar Componentes Web**.

---

#### Versión JS DOM

En la version JS DOM del Componente Web de @gerarca, se necesita accesar al elemento `div` con `getElementById`, esto con la finalidad de transformar el valor de su propiedad `style.display`, dependiendo de la posición del `Scroll`:

```
const ishow = 115
const $divtop = document.getElementById("div-totop")
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    if(document.documentElement.scrollTop > ishow){
        $divtop.style.display = "inherit"
    }
    else {
        $divtop.style.display = "none"
    }
```

Hay que tener en mente, que el `div` y su contenido ya se devolvieron (render) desde que se cargo el programa JS y la página HTML en el Explorador Web. La solución es mantener una referencia al elemento `div` desde Javascript y transformar las propiedades que se requieran, durante el evento `Scroll`:

```
<div id="div-totop" class="cmn-divfloat">
    <a href="#span-top" class="btn btn-primary cmn-btncircle">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

---

#### Versión ReactJS

Ahora, en ReactJS en vez de mantener una referencia al elemento DOM del componente con JS, se puede devolver nuevamente el Componente Padre con todos sus elementos (re-render), pero con cambios en variables de estado, los cuales permitirán manipular el Componente Web de otra forma.

Para este caso, en vez de transformar la propiedad `style.display` del elemento `div`, se puede declarar una bandera de estado con ReactJS, que indique cuando se puede ver el mismo; se usa un operador condicional ternario para describir esta lógica y se envuelve el botón en un componente hijo `BotonFlotante`:

```
 {(flag) ? <BotonFlotante /> : null }
```

A continuación, se usa una función Hook llamada [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), esta función se configura con una variable de estado `flag`, una función handler `setButtonFlag` y un valor inicial para `flag`, en este caso `false`:

```
const [flag, setButtonFlag] = useState(false);
```

Reutilizando la lógica original, cuando el `scroll` alcance cierto valor, se transforma el estado de la bandera `flag` y se le pide a ReactJS que devuelva todo el Componente padre de nuevo (re-render); este re-render se dispara automaticamente cada que se llama a la función handler del estado `setButtonFlag`, se pasa como argumento el nuevo valor para la variable de estado `flag`:

```
function handlerScroll(){
        const ishow = 115;
        if(document.documentElement.scrollTop > ishow){
            setButtonFlag(true);
        }
        else {
            setButtonFlag(false);
        }
      }
```

En vez de usar la función `IIFE` al cargar el componente, se puede usar una funcion Hook de ReactJS llamada [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), la cual dispara efectos al cargar un componente y se puede configurar este disparo de diferentes formas; para este caso se configura el disparo, solo cuando se carge el componente ReactJS:

```
  //el array de dependencias se configura vacio
  //y useEffect solo se dispara una vez, parecido a la funcion IIFE
  useEffect(()=>{
      //codigo
  },[])
```

Es aquí donde se registra el `eventListener` del `scroll`en el objeto global `window`, también se remueve cada que el componente haga un re-render:

```
    useEffect(()=>{
      window.addEventListener("scroll", handlerScroll);
      //se limpia la memoria en cada re-render
      return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handlerScroll);
  },[])
```

Estos cambios parecen ajustar bien al diseño original en JS DOM. Aquí el ejemplo ReactJS completo:

```js
function App(){
  const [flag, setButtonFlag] = React.useState(false);
  
  React.useEffect(()=>{
      function handlerScroll(){
        const ishow = 115;
        if(document.documentElement.scrollTop > ishow){
            setButtonFlag(true);
        }
        else {
            setButtonFlag(false);
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener("scroll", handlerScroll);
      //se limpia la memoria en cada re-render
      return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handlerScroll);
  },[])

  return(
    <div className="customdiv">
      <h3>Container</h3>
      {(flag) ? <BotonFlotante /> : null }
    </div>
  )
}

function BotonFlotante(){
  return (
    <div id="div-totop" className="cmn-divfloat">
      <button className="cmn-btncircle">click me</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.cmn-divfloat {
  position: fixed !important;
  bottom: 45px;
  right: 15px;
  display: inherit;
}
.cmn-btncircle {
  width: 40px !important;
  height: 40px !important;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}
.customdiv {
  min-width: 10px;
  min-height: 1000px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Como se puede observar, diseñar con ReactJS requiere que se cambie el modelo mental que se tiene al diseñar con JS DOM.

En este ejemplo, se puede ver como rediseñar el código, trabajando con copias del árbol vDom, en vez de manipular elementos del árbol DOM y sus propiedades directamente con JS.

---

#### Notas de campo

- Nótese que la clase CSS `.cmn-divfloat` tiene su propiedad `display:inherit` por defecto en el diseño ReactJS, solo se usan las propiedades de posición.
- Nótese que en ReactJS se usa la propiedad `className`, en vez de `class` para todos los elementos vDOM.
- Esta propuesta se puede mejorar, conforme avances en tus estudios de ReactJS, encontrarás mejores patrones.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Mil gracias amigo!!!! joder debo decirlo, se ve que tienes bastante experiencia con react js

Comment: Saludos colega.