# Seleccionar elementos del dom reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Como puedo seleccionar unos elementos del DOM usando reactJs, con javascript utilizaba lo que es el querySelector, getElementById, etc, pero en React es correcto usar estos mismo?, suponiendo que quiero seleccionar un menu para mostrarlo u ocultarlo con un icono hamburguesa, puedo hacer uso del querySelector dentro del functional component, donde al icono le agrego un onClick que me llame a una  funcion(showMenu) y aqui dentro poder seleccionar el menu(querySelector('.menu'), y agregarle aqui mismos los estilos o clases de css necesario para mostrarlo/ocultarlo

Comment: Creo que el metodo que buscas es `useRef` de React, hecha un vistazo por aca https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: [Aquí una publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/427947/typeerror-cannot-read-property-style-of-null/428046#428046) con un ejemplo muy parecido a lo que quieres lograr, se maneja una bandera de estado para mostrar/ocultar un fragmento del DOM. Vota por ella si fue de ayuda, saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para el problema que quieres solucionar, no es necesario utilizar user ref.
Lo que necesitas es un estado que controle si el menu se encuentra abierto o cerrado, y que el onClik al que haces referencia se encargue de modificar ese estado.

Te dejo un ejemplo simple, que solamente actualiza un texto, pero la lógica es similar a lo que estas buscando:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Menu = ({ open }) => <h1>{open ? "Menu Abierto" : "Menu Cerrado"}</h1>;

export default function App() {
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleMenu = () => setMenuOpen(prevState => !prevState);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggleMenu}>
        {menuOpen ? "Cerrar Menu" : "Abrir Menu"}
      </button>
      <Menu open={menuOpen} />
    </div>
  );
}
```